# How should we handle questions when the asker is not in a position to provide more detail or enact solutions?

Tags: discussion

A [recent question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116996/what-can-i-do-about-warm-water-coming-out-when-it-should-be-cold-no-matter-how) came up where there is a problem with the water in the OPs apartment - in fact, all of the apartments in the building. The OP is just a tenant there, and is not part of the management or maintenance team.

Therefore, the OP will likely not be able to provide clarifications, additional information, etc that are typically asked for - the OP can't go into other apartments and get pictures, nor can they take apart plumbing fixtures - and the OP will be unable to implement any (building-wide) solution to the problem. In fact, the OP may be limited in implementing solutions in their own apartment given their renter status. In this particular case, there are already several comments asking for more details. It seems reasonable to close as missing information, too broad, or unclear.

However, there may be enough information for somebody to provide an answer to the question, even if the OP is not able to implement it. Therefore, it seems reasonable to leave it open for future visitors who have a similar problem.

How should we handle these types of questions? Leave the ones open which have enough information, and close the ones that don't? Wait to see if anyone can answer, and only then close?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that the treatment of a question should be different depending upon the tenure status of the questioner.

It is true that, in some cases, a tenant may not be able to provide all the information needed to obtain a complete answer but there are freeholders who are in that same position.  Each question should be treated on its own merits.

On the specific question that you referenced, it is possible that the comments have given the OP some questions to ask the landlord.  That may get his problem fixed.  That in turn may result in a self-answer that could help others in a similar position.

I believe that any question which has comments asking for more detail should be left long enough for the detail to be provided.  If the detail isn't forthcoming in a reasonable period - then close as unclear or too broad as appropriate.  It may just take longer to receive information from a tenant who has to knock on the landlord's door to get it.